# How to use GROUP BY in GreenDao

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao, greendao-generator

I have found few questions related to this issue in SO, but did not help me much.I want to construct a query in Android using GreenDao library, query should grab all the rows containing particular phonenumber in descending order of datetime and I also want to group them by group name.
My query:

```
   List<activity> activities = activityDao.queryBuilder().where(Properties.Contact_number.eq(phonenumber)).orderDesc(Properties.Date_time).build().list();
```

How to include GROUP BY in above query so as to group the rows by `group_name`(I have group_name as column in table)?

I did not find any GROUP BY method in GreenDao,not sure if I am correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is not supported by GreenDao.
You can use this trick :

```
where(new WhereCondition.StringCondition(Properties.Contact_number.eq(phonenumber) + "GROUP BY group_name")).orderDesc(Properties.Date_time).build().list();
```

It let you build your where clause using String.

Comment: Thank you.But, I also want to arrange them descending order of  dateTime.

Comment: updated answer. Here you just have to build your where clause 'manually' then you can do as before

Comment: @Naroju is it working for you? I'm using this one but it keeps crashing